# Why do hyperlinks stop working when opening certain emails in new tabs on Outlook Web?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, outlook-web-app

When I open an email in new tab in chrome from outlook 365 web app, all my hyperlinks stops working but for some emails I received it is working.

I am generating email using power automate and html code i am using is

```
<a href=“url” target=“_blank”> click here! </a>
```

Comment: Do you have any examples that you would like to share? Maybe a screenshot of the original email and then the email when you open it in a new tab?

Comment: Are they looking like spam?

Comment: @Hermanboxcar opened email looks exactly the same, as it is some confidential email so I cannot share

Comment: Oh, try sending yourself a test email with text and a hyperlink, and opening it in a new tab, see if the issue persists.

Comment: Does the hyperlink show up in the bluish color that links usually take or an underline, or does it look like ordinary text?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the target attribute from the hyperlink. The `_blank` value opens the linked document in a new window or tab

Comment: I think they are asking about the links not working, not how to redirect instead of open a new tab.